# While loading page in mozilla, First DIV code is not loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

While loading page in mozilla, First DIV code is not loaded
tried to load html using inside

```
<div id="mainContent"></div>
```

with below call

```
if (destinationURL != null) {
$.get(destinationURL, function(data) 
{               
  $("#mainContent").attr("innerHTML",data); 
});
}
```

destinationURL refers below sample html

```
<div id="A1">
<div id="B1">
    <div id="c1">
        <span>hi</span>
    </div>
    <div id="c2"></div>
</div>
    <div id="B2">
    <div id="D1">
        <span>hi2</span>
    </div>
    <div id="D2"></div>
</div>
<div id="B3">
    <div id="E1"></div>
    <div id="E2"></div>
</div>
<div id="B4">
    <div id="F1"></div>
    <div id="F2"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

but, when html loads

```
$("#c1") refers null object
```

if i see

```
$("#D1") contains html.
```

if i give alert message on onLoad, i can able to get Html. Its happening only in mozilla

Comment: While you have had a couple of answers, none of them actually explain the problem — which is that `innerHTML` is not an HTML attribute — http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/attributes.html — Internet Explorer just has problems telling the difference between attributes and DOM properties.

Comment: Mozilla, as a browser, has been dead and gone for many years. It's primary successor is Firefox and its engine is Gecko. There are other browsers beyond IE and Firefox though, and it is worth testing in them too (especially if you have a problem with a difference between IE and Firefox).

Answer (score 2):

```
is this right express what you intended?



   $("#mainContent").attr("innerHTML",data); 



=> I think this expression will give you the answer you want.



  $("#mainContent").html(data);
```

Comment: .html() is a good way to modify the DOM, but using javascript directly instead of jquery would be a better option here

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practice to stick to javascript instead of going for Libraries unless required, the code in javascript for same would be

```
if (destinationURL != null) {
$.get(destinationURL, function(data) 
{               
  document.getElementById("mainContent").innerHTML = data; 
});
}
```

on another note, I would suggest you to build the entire structure in a string first and then insert it in DOM. Modifying DOM again and again should be avoided.

Comment: instead of $.get, i used $.ajax and async made it as false. now it is working... i feel, making async false will effect performance. i tried to use normal javascript as you said earlier...even though it is working.